# Can I select a DOM element based on an HTML comment it contains?

Tags: html, dom, xpath, css-selectors

Using either CSS3 or XPath expressions, I'd like to know if there is a way to select the element that contains certain HTML comment.

For example:

```
<table>…</table>
<table> <!--this one --> …</table>
```

How can I select the 2nd `table` without using any other attributes? (it may not always be the 2nd table)

Comment: With JavaScript, yes, but I'm not sure about using xpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With XPath this can be done using the `comment()` node test:

```
//table[.//comment()[contains(., 'this one')]]
```

This selects all `table` elements containing a comment (at any depth) that contains the text `'this one'`.

I'm pretty sure this is impossible with CSS.

Comment: Indeed impressive and useful. Thanks!

Comment: Most online xpath testers want properly formed xml, but [this one](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) works for testing html that wouldn't pass strict xml checking, like this one.

Comment: XPath was never intended for matching HTML, I believe, only XML. That's why there are so few online testers that support tag soup, even though there are libraries out there that use XPath with HTML DOMs @Henry

Comment: And yes, this is impossible with CSS, since comment nodes are not visible to CSS.